# How to launch Android emulator in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded android-sdk-linux and copied it to my local drive and extracted it. Now, when I try to create an emulator in avd manager and launch the emulator, it does not launch. It requires an environment variable of platforms and platforms-tools directory which is in android-sdk-linux. How I can create an environment variable of these two dir in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Open your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc with an editor, find the export of PATH and add:

```
export PATH=/path/to/sdk/platforms:/path/to/sdk/tools:/path/to/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

This should fix your problem. But I recommend to use the Eclipse ADT plugin. See [this article](http://avedo.net/92/eclipse-with-adt-plugin-under-ubuntu-12-04/) for installation hints.

Answer (score 1):

there is one error in previous answer, as i don't have enough reputation i can't add comment.

> export PATH=/path/to/sdk/platforms:/path/to/sdk/tools:/path/to/sdk/platform-tools:PATH

the above line  PATH keyword should be $PATH. like below

> export PATH=/path/to/sdk/platforms:/path/to/sdk/tools:/path/to/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

early i tried the previous solution my system not able to login after logout.

Comment: Thanks, Normally I would indicate this was a comment on a prior answer, but you have addressed a problem with an answer that you could not correct otherwise.  I will make an edit to the answer that you are addressing.